# About Laplace transform

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

I dont understand the following working, why the integral becomes double integral?
$$\begin{align}
  & \ \ \ \int_{0}^{1}{{{\left( \frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{1-x} \right)}^{2}}\text{d}x}=\mathcal{L}\left[ \frac{\left(t-1+{{\text{e}}^{-t}}\right)^2}{{{t}^{2}}} \right]=\int_{s}^{\infty }{\int_{u}^{\infty }{\mathcal{L}\left[ {{\left( v-1+{{\text{e}}^{-v}} \right)}^{2}} \right]}}\text{d}v\text{d}u \\ 
 & =\int_{s}^{\infty }{\int_{u}^{\infty }{\left( \frac{2}{{{v}^{3}}}-\frac{2}{{{v}^{2}}}+\frac{1}{v}+\frac{2}{{{\left( v+1 \right)}^{2}}}-\frac{2}{v+1}+\frac{1}{v+2} \right)\text{d}v\text{d}}}u \\ 
 & =\int_{s}^{\infty }{\left( \frac{1}{{{u}^{2}}}-\frac{1}{u}-\ln u-\frac{2}{u+1}-2\ln \left( u+1 \right)+\ln \left( u+2 \right) \right)}\text{d}u \\ 
 & =\frac{1}{s}+\left( 2+s \right)\left( \ln s+\ln \left( s+2 \right)-2\ln \left( s+1 \right) \right) \\ 
\end{align}$$

Comment: Where did the $s$ come from?

Comment: @rlgordonma I dont get it as well :(

Comment: @Ryan: is there some bit of information about the problem we are overlooking? Composition of product of functions or something? Regards

Comment: @Amzoti thats a lemma in solving this integral

Comment: @Ryan: can you write out everything about the problem as there is an important tidbit missing? Regards

Comment: @Ryan: Before asking the question you are posting, try to figure out this mystery with the $s$ parameter creeping in.

Comment: I think I got it...For n th degree of denominator, we hav to do n th integral.